# ReactJS setState changes not propagating from parent to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two simple reactjs components with a parent-child relationship. The child contains an input with an onChange event and a callback to the parent to setState. When I run it, setState appears to work in the parent component, but the props passed into the child component don't appear to be updating. Any ideas? Here's a code snippet:

```
var FooInput = React.createClass({
  handleInputChange: function(e) {
    this.props.onInputChange(e.target.name, e.target.value);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input name="foo" value={this.props.foo} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var FooApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      foo: 'bar',
    };
  },
  handleInputChange: function(key, value) {
    this.setState({key: value});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FooInput
            foo={this.state.foo}
            onInputChange={this.handleInputChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

In the example above, the value of input in the `FooInput` child component stays as "bar" despite the fact that `handleInputChange` is triggered in the `FooApp` parent component and foo is passed into the child component via `this.props`. Why doesn't the input value change to reflect the new state?

Answer (score 3):

You're literally setting a state variable called `key` by doing `this.setState({key: value})`. If you want a variable key, you can use brackets:

```
handleInputChange: function(key, value) {
    this.setState({[key]: value});
}
```

Or create a new object.

```
handleInputChange: function(key, value) {
    const newState = {};
    newState[key] = value;
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot that Javascript keys are interpreted as string literals. Thanks a lot for pointing it out, this was driving me nuts!